# How to Plot DBSCAN clustering R output

Tags: r, plot, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, dbscan

I am trying to cluster customer data based on their spatial locations. Here is what I have done,

```
#Reading the data
theData <- read.csv("Customer_Segmentation/data.csv")

#Subsetting only long, lat and record id.
inputdata <- data.frame(long=theData$LONG, lat=theData$LAT, RecordID=theData$RecordID)

#Building distance matrix
library(fossil)
d = earth.dist(inputdata, dist = TRUE) 

#Applying DBSCAN Clustering
library(fpc)
ds <- dbscan(d,eps = 0.5,MinPts = 50, method = "dist")
```

It is giving me some 23 clusters,

```
dbscan Pts=14873 MinPts=50 eps=0.5
      0   1  2  3   4   5  6  7  8  9   10  11 12  13  14 15  16   17 18 19 20  21  22  23
border 6546  73 47 38  20  53 60 27 70 19   93  43 58  25  21 31  36  492 47 44 41  43  55  35
seed      0 757 12 26  84  84  6 36  6 50 2132  70  2 101  91 55 104 2908 22 23 42  82  59 104
total  6546 830 59 64 104 137 66 63 76 69 2225 113 60 126 112 86 140 3400 69 67 83 125 114 139
```

First question --> How do I plot these clusters in a map? It will be great if someone point me to some sample code to plot the clusters, I tried to plot this in New Zealand map. I tried to download the coordinates and transform as below,

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
nz1 <- getData("GADM", country = "NZ", level = 1)
nz1 <- spTransform(nz1, CRS = CRS("+init=epsg:2135"))
```

But getting this error in my MAC,

```
Error in spTransform(nz1, CRS = CRS("+init=epsg:2135")) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'CRSobj' in selecting a method for function 'spTransform': Error in CRS("+init=epsg:2135") : no system list, errno: 2
```

Second question, I read somewhere that k-means is not good for spatial clustering, Then, I tried to cluster this using hierarchical clustering, but it has produced a large dendrogram, more dense one, so couldn't get any info from that. And so chosen DBSCAN to do this. But in this one, I can see some many points falling in the border as the result suggests. I am sure that I need around 50-70 customers in each cluster. But what eps value should I choose? Here is my sample data.

```
      long       lat RecordID
1 174.9066 -41.20867       90 
2 174.9093 -41.22624       91 
3 174.8893 -41.21618       92 
4 174.8973 -41.21133       93
5 174.9153 -41.20419       94
6 174.9239 -41.20167       95
```

Updating my session info as requested,

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_NZ.UTF-8/en_NZ.UTF-8/en_NZ.UTF-8/C/en_NZ.UTF-8/en_NZ.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] raster_2.3-40 rgdal_0.9-2   sp_1.1-0     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_3.1.2      lattice_0.20-29 tools_3.1.2
```

Updated library(rgdal) output as requested,

```
library(rgdal)
rgdal: version: 0.9-2, (SVN revision 526)
Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 1.11.2, released 2015/02/10
Path to GDAL shared files: /usr/local/share/epsg_csv
Loaded PROJ.4 runtime: Rel. 4.9.1, 04 March 2015, [PJ_VERSION: 491]
Path to PROJ.4 shared files: (autodetected)
Warning message:
package ‘rgdal’ was built under R version 3.1.3
```

Note:- **I have clearly mentioned that I am trying to plot the spatial clustering output and looking for the options and one of my option has got error. And there is one more question to cover the border cluster values.**

Comment: You will need to share some data for someone to reproduce your errors.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. And it is not related to my data. If you see the error, I am getting it while transforming the downloaded coordinates, which anyone can do using that same piece of code. library(sp)
library(rgdal)
nz1 <- getData("GADM", country = "NZ", level = 1)
nz1 <- spTransform(nz1, CRS = CRS("+init=epsg:2135")) . If you still need the data, I can share. Basically my question is how to plot the cluster results in map.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2013-May/018361.html) or [this](http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/spTransform-error-Error-in-CRS-quot-init-EPSG-26920-quot-no-system-list-errno-2-td7587591.html)?

Comment: Yup. Their answer says that they are getting the error because of using capital letters - EPSG.. But I am using proper ones, still I am getting the error. Then I reinstalled rgdal as they suggested.. Still no result.

Comment: Might be system related. You should share some data to see if anyone can reproduce your errors.

Comment: Yeah anyone can take the data. Here is the data as I already mentioned. nz1 <- getData("GADM", country = "NZ", level = 1) nz1 <- spTransform(nz1, CRS = CRS("+init=epsg:2135")) . It downloads the data from gadm.org.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about OSX systems. You might want to reword/retitle your question to focus on that part of the problem.

Comment: Thats alright. Thanks a lot for your time and help. But I am still looking for a  way to plot my spatial cluster data results in R. This is one option I have chosen to do and it is throwing some error, I consider other options as well to plot dbscan cluster results in a map. So keeping the title same.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue running the following code on my machine:

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
nz1 = getData("GADM", country = "NZ", level = 1) 
nz1 = spTransform(nz1, CRS = CRS("+init=epsg:2135"))
```

Here is my `sessionInfo()`:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.10

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] raster_2.3-40 rgdal_0.9-2   sp_1.0-17     dplyr_0.4.1   pROC_1.8     
[6] DBI_0.3.1    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] lazyeval_0.1.10 R6_2.0.1        plyr_1.8.1      magrittr_1.5   
 [5] assertthat_0.1  wakefield_0.2.0 parallel_3.2.0  tools_3.2.0    
 [9] Rcpp_0.11.4     grid_3.2.0      lattice_0.20-31
```

I am pretty sure this is system-related. I do not work with geo-spatial data, so had to set up all the requirements from scratch.

1. Set up the latest version of GDAL from `ppa:ubuntugis`, based on advice [here](http://www.sarasafavi.com/installing-gdalogr-on-ubuntu.html).
2. I then installed `gdal-bin`, `libgdal1-dev` & `libproj-dev`.
3. I installed R packages `raster` and `rgdal`.

### Edit:

As per @RobertH's suggestion, adding `rgdal` package load time messages:

```
rgdal: version: 0.9-2, (SVN revision 526)
Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 1.11.2, released 2015/02/10
Path to GDAL shared files: /usr/share/gdal/1.11
Loaded PROJ.4 runtime: Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012, [PJ_VERSION: 480]
Path to PROJ.4 shared files: (autodetected)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your experimentation. I tried the same and its not working for me. Could you please let me know how did you install the R packages? I am installing it through Rstudio.

Comment: @jeevag I would say you should post your `sessionInfo()` to the question. I am on a Linux machine, and things are easy. For Linux packages, I use the terminal, and for the R packages, I installed from within RStudio.

Comment: Thanks for that. I have updated my sessionInfo() in the question itself. Please check.

Comment: Also please show the messages printed by `library(rgdal)` --- to see if you have `PROJ.4`

Comment: @RobertH Sure do -- please see the added output from onLoad messages.

Comment: Thanks @fg-nu, but I meant to ask @jeevag. You have an oddly old PROJ.4  ( I am at `Rel. 4.9.1, 04 March 2015, [PJ_VERSION: 491]` ).